# Combine two SAS datasets into one .dat file

Tags: sas

I have two datasets in two different SAS tables that also have completely different data structures.  I am being asked (not my idea) to export these datasets to one .dat file and essentially stack them on top of each other using a fixed width method. The below listed snippet of data is how the export should ultimately look when it gets to the .dat file.  The first row is the result of the first dataset. The second row is result of the second dataset.

```
UH      INCR000000XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXX  SFLXXXXXXXXXXXX 000     M SMITH      XXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXX9991231
```

I cant figure out exactly how to do this.  Below is the code I've come up with that exports the data but the second data step just overwrites the first.

Comment: Missing the code...think the key is to use the Append option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the MOD option on the FILE statement.
Note this may not work on all OS's.

```
filename test1 '/home/reeza/Demo1/testfile.dat';

data exportClass;
set sashelp.class;
file test1;
if _n_=1 then do;
put @1 "Name" @20 "Age" @30 "Sex";
end;
put @1 Name @20 Age @30 Sex;
run;



data exportClass;
set sashelp.class;
file test1 mod;
if _n_=1 then do;
put @1 "Name" @20 "Weight" @30 "Height";
end;
put @1 Name @20 Weight @30 Height;
run;

filename test1;
```